# xcode 4.2.1 - storyboard - viewDidLoad issue

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, storyboard

I created my app using StoryBoard. Then, I added objective-c class to have `.h` and `.m` files for one of the views.

The problem is that I do not get `ViewDidLoad` because they are `UIView` types. xcode keep giving me errors when it sees any `[super xxx]` when I try to write `viewDidLoad` by my self.

I tried `(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`   but stil does not do what I want. because I am loading a `UIPickerView` and I want to move one of the components to specific row as follow:
`[datepick selectRow:1433 inComponent:2 animated:YES]`
which does not work if this code is in`-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`
Any idea?

Anybody knows how can I add a `UIViewController` and have the xib shown in my storyboard? or how to fix my issue?

I am really struggling with them.

Comment: viewDidLoad is a view controller method. What view controller is your picker view embedded in? Also, if you want to set specific values in UIView subclasses that are contained in a nib / storyboard, try overriding `awakeFromNib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you built your app using Storyboard, I think the problem you're having is that you 'drag and dropped' the object VIEW from the object column on the right, instead of VIEW CONTROLLER.

In a View Controller, you do have ViewDidLoad.

If this is not an answer to your problem, tell me so that I can help you furthermore!

[image]

Comment: I dragged a view controller. and I can not assign a UIViewController class to its view!! Also, dragging a viewController object does not give a header file. I have to add it manually and assign it.

Comment: do you have "@interface myViewController : UIViewController" in your .h file ?

Comment: also when I create it as a UIViewController it gives me the following error after running the app   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: This is a different error: it can mean different things, but usually it means that you have some objects in your .xib linked to some IBActions/IBOutlets that you deleted.

Select each object in your .xib files, and using the menu View => Utilities => Show Connections Inspector, see if your objects are linked to Actions/Outlets that do not exist anymore.

Comment: You are right Cookiki the error because of a UIPickerView. It worked fine after deleting it. Thanks.